# Как избежать дублирования записей в БД даже с проверкой их существования?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код, теоретически не допускающий дублирования в базе по полям `$slon_code и $service_id` (составной уникальный ключ не делал, думаю пока разобраться без него, да и разобраться в целом в дублировании).

Суть класса - парсинг и кеширование инфы.

Основной метод класса `get_response()`: есть слон `isset_slon()` - проверяем время, выдаем из бд как из кеша или парсим, нет слона - добавляем в базу `add_slon()`, затем парсим и записываем инфу в слона, выдаем юзеру.

**Проблема**: почему-то в базе появляются дубликаты по полям `$slon_code и $service_id`. Не вижу смысла добавлять проверку `isset_slon()` внутрь `add_slon()`, ведь добавление итак проходит проверку внутри `get_response()` и попадает в ветку `else` то есть `isset_slon() == false`.

Так вот в чем дело: при неправильной работе isset_post() **работа дальнейшего кода бессмысленна** (а ведь речь не об этом методе, а любом работающим с sql-запросами). Как быть, что делать?

**Вопросы:**

1. Почему происходит дублирование записей в БД? (на 5000 слонов появилось 25 дубликатов)
2. Как порешить проблемку?
3. Как работают CMS где для генерации веб-страницы используются сотни sql-запросов?

**Updated 8.12.2016**

Завел маленький лог, вторая строка это microtime(true). Видно что запись найдена, и после этого все равно идет добавление.

```
Date: 08.12.2016 13:51:28 
1481194288.9353
slon_code: 125125125 service_id: 1
slon_code в базе есть, проверяем таймаут


Date: 08.12.2016 13:51:29 
1481194289.5376
slon_code: 125125125 service_id: 1
slon_codeа в базе нет, придется парсить с нуля
slon_code добавлен в базу


Date: 08.12.2016 13:51:29 
1481194289.5627
slon_code: 125125125 service_id: 1
slon_codeа в базе нет, придется парсить с нуля
slon_code добавлен в базу


Date: 08.12.2016 13:51:29 
1481194289.5887
slon_code: 125125125 service_id: 1
slon_codeа в базе нет, придется парсить с нуля
slon_code добавлен в базу
```

**Класс запроса**

```
class Resp
{

    private $slon_code;
    private $service_id;

    public function __construct($slon_code = '', $service_id = 0)
    {
        $this->slon_code = $slon_code;
        $this->service_id = $service_id;
    }

    public function get_response()
    {

        if ($this->isset_slon()) {
            //СЛОН ЕСТЬ
            //Прошло ли достаточно времени с последнего парсинга
            if ($this->can_parse()) {
                //парсим
                $this->parse_slon();
                return $this->get_slon_info();
            } else {
                //выдаем из бд (кеш)
                return $this->get_slon_info();
            }

        } else {
            //СЛОНА НЕТ!
            //добавим в базу слона/пустышку
            //по пустышке ограничиваю запросы пользователей
            $this->add_slon();

            $this->parse_slon();
            return $this->get_slon_info();
        }
    }

    private function isset_slon()
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM slon WHERE slon_code = :slon_code AND service_id = :service_id';
        $data = $this->db->select($sql, $this->slon_params());

        if ($data[0]['count'] > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private function add_slon()
    {
        //(появились одинаковые слоны в базе)
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO slon (slon_code, service_id) VALUES (:slon_code, :service_id)';
        $params = [':slon_code' => $this->slon_code, ':service_id' => $this->service_id];

        $inserted = $this->db->insert($sql, $params);

        if ($inserted) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Код класса для запроса в бд:**

```
class Database {
    public function insert(){
      //практически копия метода select() ниже
    }

    public function select($sql = '', $params = array()){
        $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        if (!empty($params)) {
            $s = $sth->execute($params);
        } else {
            $s = $sth->execute();
        }

        if (!$s) {
            //логируем ошибку, ни одной ошибки в логах пока нет
            Log::create_mysql_log($sql, $params, $sth->errorInfo());
            return false;
        }

        return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

Comment: Сложно сказать в чем проблема но видимо между вызовами isset и add что то вставляет слона. И зачем городить такой большой код с лишними обращениями к БД если уникальные ключи для того и предназначены что бы начисто исключить такие ситуации. без ключа никто никогда не сможет гарантировать что дублей не будет. На крайний случай можно конечно использовать `insert ... select ... where not exists(select ...)` но опять же вставка-проверка должна быть атомарной операцией для БД

Comment: @Mike во всем коде add_slon() встречается только один раз в методе get_response(). Если сделаю составной уникальный ключ, то придется обрабатывать ошибки БД, я такой код пока не практиковал, решил делать как полегче.

Comment: Код ошибки проверить не сложно. при некотором желании можно сделать даже без анализа ошибок (хотя на них все равно надо проверять всегда, мало ли что в БД произойдет). Но тут ощущение что во втором потоке/приложении вставка проходит. проверьте по логам web-сервера сколько раз страница записи вызывалась

Comment: Опять же вы наверняка получаете в get_slon_id id записи отдельным запросом. А в вашем случае если слон есть - то вместо count() можно сразу получить id. Если же мы делаем insert и после него ошибок нет (проверять все равно надо) то этот id доступен в http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.lastinsertid.php (есть аналогичные функции вот всех способах работы с БД)

Comment: @Mike да, get_slon_id() отдельный mysql запрос, но по сути $this->slon_id используется в логгировании и на слонов не оказывает влияния. О каком count() идет речь? внутри isset_slon() чтобы возвращался id слона вместо $data[0]['count']?

Comment: Ну да, вы фактически делаете два запроса вместо одного при наличии записи. Сначала вызываете isset которая делает count() если она сказала что запись есть вы еще раз обращаетесь к БД для получения id. Вам достаточно получить id и по нему определить что запись есть. т.е. функция isset в принципе не нужна.

Comment: @Mike нет ли примерчика вставки в базу значения (которое уже существует в базе и уникально) и обработки ошибки вставки.

Comment: ну так все просто. insert от вашего не отличается. сразу после него проверяем db_connect->errno (mysqli) или http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorcode.php, если он не 0 - значит ошибки были. Если при этом он 1062 (для MySQL) то это ошибка дублирования.

Comment: @Mike ок, сенкс, подумаю на досуге.

Comment: Важный вопрос: код выполняется параллельно в несколько потоков или активен только один поток (например, запущен из крона только один экземпляр)? race condition - да, основная головная боль в конкурентной обработке. А обработка ошибок в PDO - это просто. Переключите `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` в единственный адекватный режим `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` и всё. Если `PDOException` прилетел - значит случилась ошибка. А пока не прилетел - значит и ошибок не было.

Comment: @Мелкий к скрипту обращаются 5-10 тысяч человек в сутки.

Comment: @Jean-Claude так в чем собственно вопрос? вы не понимаете, почему при одновременных запросах вставляются два слона? какого именно ответа вы ждете?

Comment: @PashaPash пожалуй да, жду объяснение принципа работы mysql при одновременных запросах. За уникальный ключ я понял из первого коммента.

Comment: @Jean-Claude ну как бы все достаточно очевидно. ваш код выполняется одновременно для двух запросов в два потока. поток 1 проверяет на существование - получает fasle. поток 2 проверяет существование - получает false. поток 1 вставляет запись. поток 2 вставляет запись. вы получаете дубликат.

Comment: @Jean-Claude я к тому, что у вас один php-скрипт. но он выполняется одновременно в нескольких потоках. т.е. для каждого запроса запускается копия, которая работает параллельно с остальными. и пока одна копия проходит путь от проверки до вставки - вторая вполне успевает вставить запись. при этом код работает "пошагово и линейно" в рамках одного конкретного запроса.

Comment: @Jean-Claude попробуйте пошагово нарисовать одновременное выполнение своего скрипта в два потока - и увидите почему у вас "не срабатывает проверка"

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо, буду иметь в виду.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, Вы слишком однобоко подходите к решению задачи. Где мнение MySQL-сервера по поводу происходящего? Синхронизируйте время на серверах PHP и MySQL (если они на разных хостах). Выполните всё описанное в апдейте, ещё раз. Полученный лог дополните выпиской из General Log с mySQL-сервера. Тогда будет предмет для обсуждения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему конкретно происходит дублирование записей исходя из предоставленного кода сказать невозможно. Очевидно лишь что функция добавления записи где-то по какой-то причине вызывается дважды. Самая очевидная причина - повторный запрос от браузера, существование которого можно посмотреть по логам сервера (`access_log`).

Предположим что браузер действительно делает два запроса по неизвестной причине, которую вы не можете устранить (бывает и такое). Предположим вы будете обнаруживать этот второй запрос и выдавать ошибку. Этим вы не столько не решите проблему, сколько создадите дополнительные неудобства для ваших пользователей: с высокой вероятностью они увидят не результат выполнения первого (успешного) запроса, а сообщение об ошибке. Потом будут писать вам и вы будете тратить время и силы на объяснение очевидного...

Принципиально решить эту проблему можно возвращая сообщение об успешном добавлении даже если запись просто существует. Ведь пользователям не столько важно знать добавилась ли запись в самом деле, сколько важно знать что запись, которая им нужна, в базе всё-таки, в конце концов, существует.

Для этого вам нужно использовать уникальный ключ по колонкам `slon_code` и `service_id`.

```
ALTER TABLE `slon` ADD UNIQUE( `slon_code`, `service_id`);
```

В комментариях вы пишите что пока не практиковали обработку ошибок БД. В вашем случае без этого можно обойтись, использовав синтаксис `INSERT IGNORE`.

Если функция `get_slon_id()` делает отдельный запрос и код ожидает что функция `add_slon` вернёт *факт* существования новой записи, то вся измененная процедура добавления будет такая:

```
private function add_slon()
{
    // добавили IGNORE
    $sql = 'INSERT IGNORE INTO slon (slon_code, service_id) VALUES (:slon_code, :service_id)';
    $params = [':slon_code' => $this->slon_code, ':service_id' => $this->service_id];

    $inserted = $this->db->insert($sql, $params);
    $this->slon_id = $this->get_slon_id();
    // проверяем что ID найден, значит какая-то вставка точно удалась
    return (bool) $this->slon_id;
}
```

Если же нужно всё-таки проверять каждый раз что запись именно что добавилась, то придётся всё-таки начать практиковать обработку ошибок.

Рекомендуемый в другом ответе подход с [блокированием таблицы](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/lock-tables.html) (`LOCK TABLES ...`) саму проблему одновременного добавления записей не решает.

Comment: да, буду добавлять уникальный составной ключ. Пока что так никто и не объяснил почему может происходить дублирования кроме намека в коменте http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/599453/%d0%94%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%91%d0%94-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f#comment814095_600526

Comment: Дублирование - это легко. При каждом сохранении пишите в лог полный трейс. По нему потом будет просто понять откуда был вызов сохранения. Обычная отладка. Другое дело что не обязательно есть простой способ избежать дублирования...

Comment: выбрал ответом. На самом деле полным ответом считаю все ответы + комментарии данного вопроса, собрал ответ по крупицам, но у вас более менее компактно разложено по полочкам..

Answer (score 8):

Не верный подход. Целостность данных должно контролироваться на уровне СУБД. Желательно это контролировать через:

1. Индексы UNIQUE в БД
2. LOCK таблицы от проверки на существование до завершения вставки.
3. Или вот такой хак https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164505/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table

А лучше совместить 1 и 2

Comment: Зачем lock таблицы?

Comment: да зачем лок таблицы если как я понимаю запросы выполняются друг за другом пошагово?

Comment: наверное плохо вы понимаете. Если бы они выполнялись пошагово и линейно не было дублей с такой  проверкой.

Comment: Для парсера и кеша однопоточность редкое явление.

Comment: `пошагово и линейно` я имел в виду в одном php-скрипте.

Comment: то что оно всё в 1 скрипте не обозначается, что этот скрипт не исполняется в одни момент времени N раз. Сколько его дернули в момент времени, столько и исполнилось.

Answer (score 0):

Как верно заметили в остальных ответах, контролировать уникальность записей - это забота БД. Но использовать, все же, лучше не уникальный индекс, а первичный ключ.

```
CREATE TABLE slon(
    slon_code VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    service_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(slon_code, service_id)
);
```

И тогда при попытке вставки дубликата будет возвращаться ошибка, которая отлавливается соответствующей функцией используемого вами расширения.

Comment: первичный ключ уже есть slon_id

Comment: @Jean-Claude Если у вас в таблице есть такой первичный ключ, то вы в принципе не смогли бы добавить две записи с одинаковыми ключами. Перепроверьте, есть ли он. Если есть, то подобное поведение либо обусловлено каким-то некорректным кешированием, либо ненаучной фантастикой.

Comment: первичный slon_id автоинкрементный.

Comment: @Jean-Claude тогда вы несколько слукавили на счет дубликата slon_id. Его не могло возникнуть.

Comment: я ничего не лукавил, но всю подноготную же не могу сюда скидывать, никто не захочет заниматься крупным вопросом, поэтому в вопрос добавил самое необходимое. Дубликат в данном случае я подразумеваю - дублирование полей $slon_code и $service_id, которых не должно быть, у поля slon_id другое назначение. Да оно разное автоинкрементальное.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Это классическая ситуация, когда дают изначально неверные вводные и просят помочь разобраться. Самым лучшим выходом будет если вы опишите 1) что именно не работает, 2) как оно должно работать, 3) кусок кода, в котором это происходит. Не надуманный пример, а вот как оно есть на самом деле. Большими сложными вопросами тут никого не напугаешь. А то получается как в том анекдоте "Не выйграл, а проиграл. Не машину, а 100 рублей. Не в лотерею, а в карты"

Comment: я и написал `дублирования в базе по полям $slon_code и $service_id`? а полей может быть 100, мне их все описать?

Comment: @Jean-Claude все, я вас понял. В таком случае действительно следует использовать уникальный составной индекс. Хотя если дошло до такого, то это с большой вероятностью говорит о том, что выбрана некорректная модель данных, которая тянет за собой костыли и подпорки.

Comment: @Jean-Claude вам необходимо найти те поля в этой таблице которые будут уникально идентифицировать сущность в предметной области и использовать их либо в качестве составного первичного ключа удалив искусственный, либо просто создать на их основе индекс объявив его уникальным.